# Добавление записи лишь один раз в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как можно добавить лишь один раз запись в бд.

Comment: уникальный индекс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял, но вот так пробовали?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)");
```

А, понял :)
Да, правильно подсказывают. Установите уникальный индекс или осуществляйте проверку. Т.е. перед добавлением пробегайте по базе и ищите такую же запись.

Comment: Нет просто вот хочу сделать.Когда пользователь зарегистрировался.Заходит на сайт и загружает аватарку создавался альбом.Например. фотографии профиля.А при последующим просто делать упдейт аватарок в этот альбом, но что бы уже он не создавался.

Comment: Тогда можно использовать

`INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`

Comment: Можно просто в коде делать проверку на существование альбома, если он уже существует, то просто добавить аватарку, если не существует, то создаем альбом и добавляем аватарку.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы про запись которая уже есть в базе, то установите уникальные поля для таблицы.

Comment: Нет просто вот хочу сделать.Когда пользователь зарегистрировался.Заходит на сайт и загружает аватарку создавался альбом.Например. фотографии профиля.А при последующим просто делать упдейт аватарок в этот альбом, но что бы уже он не создавался.

Answer (score 0):

Если данные берутся из формы, то лучше сделать грамотную защиту от повторной отправки POST-запроса. Либо сделать уникальный индекс по нужным полям и игнорировать ошибку при повторном INSERT'е.